# Pass the value of an xhr onload function globally

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, xmlhttprequest

In an app I'm creating I have the below XMLHttpRequest and I'm trying to pass the results of `data` inside the `xhr.onload()` into an array that's created within the same parent function.

```
var url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?'+resource+'&'+CLIENT_ID;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, true);
xhr.onload = function(){
    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
    console.log(data.permalink_url);
};
xhr.send();
```

Below this I have the building blocks of an array and I'm trying to pass the results of data into the track string.

```
var metadata = {
        id: val,
        title: title,
        url: posturl,
        track: data.permalink_url
      };
```

Everything I've tried thus far either returns `undefined` or `function` and now I'm totally out of ideas...

Comment: Where is `metadata` used?

Comment: Directly below it, here's a fiddle with a stripped down version of the function http://jsfiddle.net/4eY6b/ - title works fine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ajax executes asynchronously (generally).  This is vital to how Ajax works.  What this means is that you can't count on the *when* the `onload` method will fire, or even *if* it will fire.  What this means is that all code that depends on the `xhr.responseText` (result of the HTTP request) has to be done within the callback itself.  For example:

```
xhr.onload = function () {
    // This will execute second
    doStuffWithData(JSON.parse(xhr.responseText));
}
// This will execute first
xhr.send();
var anything = anythingElse;
```

Answer (score 1):

Like I said in the comment to [my previous answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20204748/1397319), you can change the one line to `xhr.open('GET', url, false)`. It will make the request synchronous and will prevent everything else from running until the request completes. It will allow you to access `xhr.responseText` without waiting for an onload function.

```
CLIENT_ID = 'client_id=xxx';
var src = track,
    match = src.match(/url=([^&]*)/),
    resource = match[0],
    stream = decodeURIComponent(match[1]) + '/stream/?' + '&' + CLIENT_ID;

var url = 'http://api.soundcloud.com/resolve.json?' + resource + '&' + CLIENT_ID;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('GET', url, false);
xhr.send();

parsedResults.push({
    title: title,
    track: JSON.parse(xhr.responseText)
});
```

You can [see it in action here](http://jsbin.com/aPevEXi/1/edit?js,console). It appears to be broken in Chrome for some reason. Works in Firefox though. I assume it's something to do with the CORS + 302 redirect + synchronous request.

Answer (score 0):

I've gone for Explosion Pills solution. The only problem I encounter is that the links that get crawled don't always come back in the same order each time I run the node app. Realistically they should return in the order that they're crawled in (which would be newest posts first, right?) However this isn't always the case?